# Loading Quantum Mechanical Equation in LATEX into Sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way in Sympy to load a Quantum Mechanical Equations into a sympy expression, reading the input data in a Latex notation. I’ve tested it, so far with no success with the “sympify” and “parse_latex” functions using the string described below.

Maybe the "sympy.physics.quantum" does not yet implement this conversion in this direction.

```
myeq = r'''${\displaystyle i\hbar {\frac {d}{dt}}\vert \Psi (t)\rangle ={\hat {H}}\vert \Psi (t)\rangle }$'''
```

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: What're the errors you're getting? I installed the packages and I got a few errors. I started trimming your equation, removed `\displaystyle`, `$` and extra spaces, and `myeq2 = r'''i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}\vert \Psi(t)\rangle =\hat{H}\vert \Psi(t)\rangle'''` resulted in `i*(hbar*Derivative(vert*Psi(t), t))`, which seems to be only half the equation, and a bit wrong.

Comment: Thanks for checking this: 
   parse_latex(myeq)
Error:  TypeError: 'Latex' object is not iterable

   sympify(myeq)
SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '<IPython.core.display.Latex object>'' failed, because of exception ..
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)

   I also got a a good step forwards by removing the \displaystyle, $ and extra spaces. The equation is visible now, with an uninterpreted string "vertrangle", likely a sum of the Latex  "\vert" and "\rangle" tags.      

   The Hamiltonian denoted by Ĥ "hat H" is shown literally.

Comment: This is a tough one, I don't think it can do exactly what you what. We got close to the same results and there's not much we can tweak, AFAIK. Did you look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256644/convert-latex-to-sympy-format ? Maybe you can use the second tool to work something out.